# Plot according to row count in time series

Tags: r, plot, group-by, time-series, row

I have a table including two columns namely **date** and **username** and I would like to plot count of each user record by day or month on R.

Is there any way to do it directly?

My table;

```
User   Time
a      2016-05-02 03:45:11 
b      2016-05-05 04:05:24 
b      2016-06-05 07:23:16 
c      2016-05-08 08:37:37 
d      2016-05-09 11:28:15 
c      2016-08-11 23:41:18 
c      2016-05-11 03:51:14 
b      2016-05-11 06:16:21 
b      2016-07-15 20:23:35 
a      2016-05-16 06:42:53 
a      2016-05-17 08:52:24 
a      2016-05-18 09:35:47 
a      2016-05-19 03:24:39 
d      2016-07-12 06:39:26 
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

I would like to show the activity level of each user within time in the same plot to compare each of them. It would be line graph or would be another type of graph that you think is better.

This question would be so basic but I could not see any direct solution  that I have searched till now. Please also consider that I am newbie for that.

Comment: There are three plotting paradigms (base, lattice, ggplot2) and a couple of data-management paradigms. This seems fairly basic and you really should edit your question so there is a specific R object to work with. We cannot tell whether you actually have R Date objects or factor variables. In the meantime, I'm voting to close as unclear, but if you edit to make more specific, I'd be happy to reverse that vote. Example construction is _your_ responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

As always reproducible data using `dput` with expected output will be helpful. But, here is my best shot based on your data. However, better visualisation is required.

```
df <- structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
Time = c("2016-05-02 03:45:11", "2016-05-05 04:05:24", "2016-06-05 07:23:16", 
"2016-05-08 08:37:37", "2016-05-09 11:28:15", "2016-08-11 23:41:18", 
"2016-05-11 03:51:14", "2016-05-11 06:16:21", "2016-07-15 20:23:35", 
"2016-05-16 06:42:53", "2016-05-17 08:52:24", "2016-05-18 09:35:47", 
"2016-05-19 03:24:39", "2016-07-12 06:39:26")), .Names = c("User", 
"Time"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), class = "data.frame")


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df_clean <- df %>% group_by(User, hour(Time)) %>%     #To prepare for calculating User per hour, For day use day() function from lubridate
mutate(n = n()) %>% distinct(User,n) %>%              #Remove duplicted users
ungroup() %>%  group_by(`hour(Time)`) %>% mutate(label_ypos=cumsum(n) - 0.5*n)      #Labels positions on the graph

ggplot(data=df_clean, aes(x=`hour(Time)`, y=n, fill=User)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity",position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
 geom_text(aes(y=label_ypos, label=n), vjust=.5, 
        color="white", size=3.5)
```

[image]